# How would I be able to convert this jQuery code to React Native?

Tags: jquery, reactjs, twitter

I'm currently working on implementing Masonry design on our news website that is also going to include Tweets. However, due to Tweets being rendered *after* Masonry loads, I was stuck.

But I found that this can be solved via jQuery; Example (https://codepen.io/ziegfiroyt/pen/KMVYPZ):

```
    // Twitter widget is loading.
  window.twttr = function (d, s, id) {
  var t, js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return; js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  return window.twttr || (t = { _e: [], ready: function (f) { t._e.push(f) } 
});
  }(document, 'script', 'twitter-wjs');

// When widget is ready, run masonry
twttr.ready(function (twttr) {
  twttr.events.bind('loaded', function (event) {
    $('.grid').masonry({
      itemSelector : '.grid-item',
      columnWidth : 300,
      gutter: 20
    });
  });
});
```

Only problem is, our entire web app is created in React and I've read that mixing jQuery and React is not favourable.

So in this scenario, is there a way to convert this jQuery code into React? It's a critical design feature of our website and we cannot progress until this has been solved.

Thanks in advance to anyone here!

Comment: Use https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-masonry-component.

Comment: @kiarashws Hey, thanks for getting back to me. AFAIK this is only the masonry component for React and doesn't help convert the above code to accommodate Tweets rendering after Masonry loads? Maybe I'm not understanding it fully?